File() only returns one array element
I'm trying to read a copy of my servers firewall deny list into an array but only one array element is returned. Here is a part of the list:
    46.229.168.0/24 # {do not delete} - Thu Nov 14 01:23:31 2019
    43.128.88.156 # lfd: Tue Dec 12 11:11:01 2023
    150.158.44.71 # lfd: t 3600 secs - Tue Dec 12 11:18:27 2023

I have tried these two methods of reading the file into an array:
    $ips = file('log.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    print_r($ips);

    $file = fopen('log.txt',"r");
    $ips = [];
    while ($line = fgets($file)) {
      $ips[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
    print_r($ips);

In both cases, the following is returned:
    Array
    (
        [0] => 46.229.168.0/24 # {do not delete} - Thu Nov 14 01:23:31 2019
    43.128.88.156 # lfd: (sshd) Failed SSH login from 43.128.88.156 (SG/Singapore/-): 5 in the last 3600 secs - Tue Dec 12 11:11:01 2023
    150.158.44.71 # lfd: (sshd) Failed SSH login from 150.158.44.71 (CN/China/-): 5 in the last 3600 secs - Tue Dec 12 11:18:27 2023
    )

I've used the file command many times so I assume the problem is in how the input file is formatted. It is just a straight copy of the servers firewall list. Am I doing something incorrectly or need to use different code?

Can you share the output of hexdump -C log.txt so we can have a look at what the bytes for those files look like?

replace while ($line = fgets($file)) with while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false)

Have you seen this note in the file() manual page? "Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem."

Thanks, Phil. I didn't notice that comment. The file was marked as a MAC file. Changing it allowed the code to work as expected.
